# Return unpacked arguments

Tags: python

Is it possible to return unpacked arguments?  What I am picturing is to `return msg, *msg_args` which would return a tuple such as `(msg, msg_args[0], msg_args[1], msg_args[2])`.  This would allow me to send it to another function for string interpolation.

```
def add_to_message(msg, *msg_args):
    msg += "  I am %s."
    msg_args = list(msg_args)
    msg_args.append("fine")
    return(msg, *msg_args)

def display_localized_message(msg, *msg_args):
    """Translate message, then interpolate and print it."""
    print(msg % msg_args)

display_localized_message(
    *add_to_message("Hi %s.  How are %s?", "Peter", "you"))
```

Desired results: print `Hi Peter.  How are you?  I am fine.`

Actual results: `SyntaxError: can use starred expression only as assignment target`.  The line containing the error is `return msg, *msg_args`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're not using Python 3.5+ with [additional unpacking generalizations](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#whatsnew-pep-448), you can't unpack as part of a return value. Just explicitly make the combined `tuple` through `tuple` concatenation:

```
return (msg,) + msg_args
```

Comment: Actually after I first posted I realized the code was using lists (see edited question), so what works for my code is `return [msg,] + msg_args`.  But that is just what I was looking for.

Comment: @JimK: Just  FYI, you don't need the trailing comma for a single element `list` literal. That's only needed for `tuple`s (to distinguish from the case of using parens for grouping).

Answer (score 1):

In python versions prior to 3.5, simply construct a new tuple using it:

```
def add_to_message(msg, *msg_args):
    msg += "  I am %s."
    msg_args.append("fine")
    return (msg,) + msg_args
```

In python 3.5, your current syntax would be fine.

Comment: The `+` method still works in Python 3.5 just to be clear.

Answer (score 0):

Simple. Just don't use the star and reference as a list.

```
def add_to_message(msg, *msg_args):
    msg += "  I am %s."
    msg_args.append("fine")
    return (msg,) + msg_args
```

The * is only used in the method definition to show that it will be a tuple of all of the rest of the arguments. Inside of the method, you reference that tuple without the star. It is just a tuple.

Comment: That returns a `tuple` where the second element is the varargs `tuple`, not a flattened version.

Comment: Now it's a `tuple` of a value and a `list`. Still not what was requested.

Comment: @ShadowRanger yeah didn't read it closely enough. Thought the issue was referenced the *msg args. The msg just needs to be added (after making it into a tuple with a single element)